# Oracle throwing SP2-1502 where there is no http_proxy variable set

Tags: windows, oracle, sqlplus, http-proxy

I have a problem trying to conect to an Oracle database via sqlplus.

The command line looks like this:

```
C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1>sqlplus
Error 46 initializing SQL*Plus
HTTP proxy setting has incorrect value
SP2-1502: The HTTP proxy server specified by http_proxy is not accessible

C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1>http_proxy
'http_proxy' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.
```

Acording to [this blog post](http://fritshoogland.wordpress.com/2007/08/31/the-strange-whereabouts-of-http_proxy-and-the-solution-in-11g-of-course/)! it apears to complain about the value on the http_proxy variable, but this variable don't even exist in the client machine.

Anyone had this same problem over windows?

---

Edit:

Sorry guys. I had http_proxy set as a user variable. I was just trying to look at it the wrong way.

Wrong:

```
C:\Users\ilson.bolzan>http_proxy
```

Right:

```
C:\Users\ilson.bolzan>echo %http_proxy%
```

Comment: What's the output of `echo %http_proxy%`?

Comment: @MarcoBaldelli Thank you. I made a mistake.
I assumed that synce typing proxy on the command line outputs the content of the variable, typing http_proxy perhaps would do the same.

Comment: also you can view velue of your variable by using: `set http_proxy`

Comment: Please, post an answer with the solution. [so] is not a forum, here you mark an answer as correct indicating the problem was solved.

Comment: Downrated due to confusing q+a. (Resolved the problem myself by unsetting all proxy variables.)

Comment: Do you think I should delete the question? I'm keeping it alive just because there are useful answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`http_proxy` is variable, so on Windows you must set this value

```
c:\>set http_proxy = whatever
```

unset value

```
c:\>set http_proxy =
```

IMHO U have problem with your ORACLE_SID variable or ORACLE_HOME variable.
Please check this variables that are correctly filled with this command: `c:\>set`

Answer (score 9):

I got the same problem on Linux.

When I unsetted 'http_proxy' environment variable as

```
unset http_proxy
or
export http_proxy=
```

the problem was repeated.

I found, that 'no_proxy' environment variable spoils the case.

I had right value for *http_proxy*

```
http_proxy=http://localhost:3128/
```

**but** I had *no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,::1* too.

I've unset 'no_proxy' environment variable and sqlplus start to work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I realise that this is an old question but am adding this as I've had a similar issue a few times and keep coming back to this post, so it may help others.

In Linux, I had both "NO_PROXY" and "no_proxy" set (different case matters).  I had to unset both of these, and left HTTP_PROXY populated.

Answer (score 1):

The **correct** way to set http_proxy and so on is the following:

```
set http_proxy="http://<proxy_address>"
```

Note - the '**http://**' at the start - some tools do a parsing on the variable and it might fail in case the protocol is missing at the start! The quotes are there for completeness; if you set it like this you will not have errors like SP2-1502.

Answer (score 1):

```
<h1><u>Just Run these command .</u></h1> 
<h3>
administrator@Rizwan:~$ unset http_proxy <br>
administrator@Rizwan:~$ unset no_proxy <br>
administrator@Rizwan:~$ sqlplus sys as sysdba<br>
</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue happens if the proxy uses authentication, as e.g. with

```
HTTP_PROXY=http://domain\\user@192.168.178.1
```

This blocked it for me. What worked to fix it was either to unset the `HTTP_PROXY` variable entirely, or kick out the `domain\\user@` part – i.e., based on above example, change it to:

```
HTTP_PROXY=http://192.168.178.1
```

The `NO_PROXY` variable however didn't disturb the process in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your bash script. It runs everytime you open a new terminal.

`sudo nano ~/.bash_profile`

set on the last line

`unset no_proxy`

I was under a proxy. So when I added `unset http_proxy` sqlplus worked but curl fucntion stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `https_proxy` from the env file helped me.

You can use `printenv` to see the env variable, and `unset https_proxy` to remove it.